# How can I access members of a derived class's base class through the Immediate window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, immediate-window

Using the Immediate (or Watch) window in Visual Studio (I'm using VS2015 Community Edition), it's possible to access properties or methods on classes while in break mode. However, for a class derived from another class I can't find a way to access the base class's members if they have been overridden in the derived class, even though this is straightforward to do from code as shown in this example:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ostrich = new Ostrich();
        ostrich.WriteType();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public void WriteType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm an {0}", this.Name);
    }

    public virtual string Name => "animal";
}

public class Ostrich : Animal
{
    public override string Name => $"ostrich, not an {base.Name}";
}
```

If I run this code, the output is (obviously):

> I'm an ostrich, not an animal

If I set a breakpoint inside the `Name` property of the `Ostrich` class, then check the `Name` property in the Immediate window, the output is as shown:

```
?this.Name
"ostrich, not an animal"
```

If instead I ask for the base class's implementation to be run, I'd expect the output to be "animal". In fact, I get this:

```
?base.Name
"ostrich, not an animal"
```

This seems to be not only unhelpful but actually misleading/incorrect: I'd rather an error were returned than the wrong answer.

Using a Watch window, only the derived class's implementation is shown:

[image: Mini-Watch window screenshot]

**Is there any way to use the Immediate window to access the overridden members of a class's base class?**

Comment: The only real problem with the expression parser that is used in the Immediate window is that it works too well and creates the illusion that it has the complete C# compiler built-in.  It just doesn't, it doesn't know beans about keywords like `base`.  Maybe some day it will be updated to use Roslyn, future music.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, this answer was enlightening for me; I had fallen for exactly the illusion you describe. +1 also for "doesn't know beans".

Answer (score 0):

I think `base.` is not publicly available outside the class. If you were writing code outside of the class implementation, to access the property of `Animal` rather than of `Ostrich` then you would bracket-cast to `Animal`.

```
((Animal)obj).Name
```

The problem is that even this will still give you `ostrich` not `animal`, since this is exactly the behaviour that overriding is supposed to achieve, i.e. that you can access the `Name` property of an object that you think is of type `Animal`, but that its functionality can be overridden in a derived class.

I'm not sure of the ins and outs of it from a compiler perspective, but it wouldn't surprise me if the code for the base implementation doesn't even end up in the compiled `Ostrich`, unless there is code in `Ostrich` which accesses `base.`

I agree that the fact that the Immediate window allows you to use `base.` and then gives you the wrong answer is confusing and likely a bug in Visual Studio, unless others can explain how this makes sense.

It would be interesting to see how the Immediate window behaves if you include some code in `Ostrich` which accesses `base.Name`